# Publishing web application works in Visual Studio, but generated package cmd file fails with insufficient permissions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

I'm trying to deploy a web application from the command line.  Eventually I'll do this from my build server (running Jenkins), but for now I'm doing it from my desktop.

My web server runs Windows Server 2012.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on the desktop. Within Visual Studio, publishing directly, using the Web Deploy method, works fine.  If instead I use the Web Deploy Package method, then run the generated .cmd file, it fails with

`Error: (3/14/2013 7:35:49 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: An error occurred when reading the IIS Configuration File 'MACHINE/REDIRECTION'. The identity performing the operation was 'WEB\uoedeploy'.Error: Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions`

Following instructions from Microsoft and elsewhere, I have created an account on the web server for publishing, and I use the same account credentials for both publishing methods. I added that user to the group MSDepSvcUsers on the web server.  I checked the effective permissions for that account on `redirection.config`, and it shows read permission.

I hate MSDeploy.

Comment: I feel your pain. I'm fighting the same thing now. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Anyone find a solution?